# Interpolate bounded pixels in python

Tags: python, image-processing, matrix, interpolation

I have a matrix of values between 0 and 1.

The matrix consists of blocks of values which are the same, but with different widths.

The image below is a visual picture of this matrix.

I would like to perform essentially a "blur" on the pixels on the condition that

1) the centre of each bounded box (bounded by black dots) remains the same

2) if the edge of a bounding box lies on the edge of the image (i.e. touches the yellow colour) the value of the centre of this line remains the same.

[image]

I expect such a function already exists but I'm not sure what it is called / how to implement it.

It should end up looking something like this

[image]

Comment: what kind of blurring do you want? Gaussian? Linear interpolation?

Comment: You are "lying", the edges don't remain the same (f.i. the discontinuities on the left side are smoothed out). Yo must improve the specification.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ah yes! Updated :)

Comment: @James: are the values elsewhere on the edges free ? What about the corners ?

Answer (score 0):

Without data, cannot test on your data, but I would do following:

a) save the original mask (yellow colors)

b) apply some smoothing to the data (either moving average or something similar)

c) mask the outcome using the original mask